# Полноценный tooltip, без костылей

Tags: c#, wpf

Как правильно организовать что то вроде подсказки(tooltip) для shape в котором можно будет изменить цвет, размеры и название(name). Я примерно представляю как это делать но я боюсь что это будет очередной костыль, который будет срабатывать через раз.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что именно вы хотите? Форматирование? Привязку данных? Что не выходит?

Comment: @VladD то и другое, то есть форматирование и привязку данных, а ещё чтобы когда я переносил курсор на сам tooltip, чтобы изменить параметр, tooltip не исчезал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С форматированием и привязкой просто. Вот сниппет:

```
<TextBlock Text="I am long text">
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Background="LightCyan" Padding="0">
            <Border BorderBrush="DarkCyan" BorderThickness="3" Padding="5">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding A, StringFormat='A = {0}'}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding B, StringFormat='B = {0}'}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

---

Для конвертации из строки в цвет фона можно использовать такой конвертер:

```
class StringToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    BrushConverter converter = new BrushConverter();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return converter.ConvertFrom(value);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

```
<TextBox Width="70">
    <TextBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Background="{Binding PlacementTarget.Text,
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                      Converter={StaticResource S2B},
                                      TargetNullValue=Yellow}"
                 MinWidth="50">
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding PlacementTarget.Text,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                              AncestorType=ToolTip},
                               StringFormat='Color = {0}'}"/>
        </ToolTip>
    </TextBox.ToolTip>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: А вот как насчёт изменения цвета у shape при onchange? Ну в смысле когда изменяешь цвет в строке, чтобы он сразу же менялся на тот цвет который я ввёл. И ещё как сделать чтобы tooltip появлялся посередине сверху shape?

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: Для точного расположения есть [Placement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Если вам хочется чего-то совсем экзотического, там для этого есть Custom.

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: Думаю, что цвет можно менять привязкой, как обычно.

Comment: а вот как работать с привязкой я просто в этом как то пытался разобраться но так и не получилось, может подскажите как всё это сделать?

Comment: Я максимум могу при изменении текста в tooltip в событии onchange получить текст потом применить полученный текст к объекту, который вызвал tooltip, но мне кажется что это можно сделать легче

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: Ну, вам надо прибиндить текст к background brush tooltip'а через конвертер. Сейчас накатаю пример.

Comment: @Alex_Rudenkiy: Смотрите пример в конце ответа. Понимает цвета в формате `#80ffc0` и `DarkCyan`.